# Dojo Store / QueryResults based on existing Async function with callback

Tags: javascript, callback, dojo, promise, deferred

I'm trying to create a Dojo Store as described here https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/creating_stores/ however I need to implement an existing data retrieval API into the query. Specifically the Mx.data.get from https://apidocs.mendix.com/7/client/mx.data.html

My QueryResults are always empty, and I guess it's because API I'm using uses a callback and does not deliver a promise.

```
query: function (query, options) {    
  var deferred = new Deferred();
  this.getResults(query, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(result);
    }
  });
  return QueryResults(deferred.promise);
},

getResults: function (query) {
  mx.data.get({
    xpath: "//System.User",
    filter: {
      sort: [["Name", "asc"]],
      offset: 0,
      amount: 10
    },
    callback: function(objs) {
      return(objs);
    }
  });
}
```

I see the code is executed, but the resulting `objs` are never returned, the `QueryResults` are always empty. (I've also tried `QueryResults(deferred)` but with the same effect.

Anyone here who can help me to make the `mx.data.get` suitable to use when making a `QueryResults`?

Answer (score 0):

And the next morning all is clear: simply needed to move the `deferred.resolve` inside the callback.

```
query: function (query, options) {    
  this.deferred = new Deferred();
  this.getResults(query);
  return QueryResults(deferred);
},

getResults: function (query) {
  mx.data.get({
    xpath: "//System.User",
    filter: {
      sort: [["Name", "asc"]],
      offset: 0,
      amount: 10
    },
    callback: lang.hitch(this, function(objs) {
        this.deferred.resolve(objs);
      });
    }
  });
}
```